# redirecting after getting data from api

Tags: api, redirect, routes

i am calling api and scenario is if the data comes from api , then it means server is running and i have to redirect to next page , if there is no data from api , i should display message server is not running . whatever the data comes is not concern , whether the data is coming or not based on that i have to redirect , how can i do this in react

useEffect(() => {
axios
.get("my api")
.then((res) => {
console.log(res);
setscene(res.data);
})
.catch((err) => {
console.log(err);
});
}, []);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the update which i had to made , if(res.status===200)
that means we are getting data from api.

```
useEffect(()=>{
     axios.get('your api')
     .then((res)=>{
        if (res.status === 200) {
         history.push('/Scenes')
      
      }else{
       alert("check the server connection")
      }
        
        setsts(res.data)
     
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}, []);
```